# Как увеличить посещаемость блога?

Tags: seo

Добрый день, согласен что это возможно вопрос не в тему данного ресурса, но все же задам. У меня есть свой блог на ресурсе blogspot.com. Хотел бы узнать если возможность его как то оптимизировать чтобы увеличить посещаемость, или кто-то может посоветовать сервис через который это можно сделать?

Comment: можно добавить туда порно

Comment: интересное предложение, но мне оно не подходит.

Comment: ну тогда надо что бы на блоге было чтото интересное, что бы люди сами хотели туда зайти, толку с накрутки? или у тебя там супер информация, которую надо донести до рядового пользователя преодолев информационный барьер?

Comment: Пишите интересный и/или уникальный контент, используйте в МЕРУ SEO и посетители не заставят себя долго ждать.

Comment: А могли бы вы привести темы которые бы вам хотелось прочитать?

Comment: см. первый коммент )

Comment: А кроме порно ничего интересного для вас нет?

Comment: А можно примеры посещаемых блогов? (именно программерской тематики)
В голову пришла только Алена C++, да и посещаемый он наверно относительно других программерских. (естественно я спрашиваю про русскоязычных блоггеров)

Comment: а почему обязательно программерских?

Comment: Просто ресурс тут такой, вот я и подумал. + посмотрел ваш блог немного

Comment: Порно не подходит так как можно легко попасть на закрытие из-за закона о цензуре. Можете ли написать темы которые отели бы почитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можете ли написать темы которые отели бы почитать?

С таким подходом у вас вряд ли что-то выйдет.

Чтобы определиться с тем, о чем писать, можно применить [круги Эйлера](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%F0%F3%E3%E8_%DD%E9%EB%E5%F0%E0):

1. Это то, что вы знаете, и о чем можете рассказать. И не просто рассказать, а грамотно и интересно рассказать. Копипаста и быдлотексты никого не интересуют.
2. Это то, о чем можно рассказывать в *этой стране*.
3. Это то, что интересно читать аудитории.

Общие моменты этих "трех" кругов - это, ради чего люди пойдут к вам в блог.

Comment: кстати, где-то ж можно достать самые популярные запросы в поисковых системах? это поможет сориентироваться.

тут например несколько указано http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=0813301182c78224&pli=1

Comment: Вот это хороший совет, спасибо.